# How to split array by four items in ngFor?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

How to split array by four items in ngFor?

How can I show here 4 projects instead of one?

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
     // How can I show here 4 projects instead of one?
     {{item}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you'r asking for. `How can I show here 4 projects instead of one?` ???

Comment: atleast show us your JSON

Comment: I think there’s a good range of answers there for you, but more info about your architecture and what you want to achieve would be needed. @stingingdafunk has the most elegant answer, but might be worth looking at my answer and the others and understanding how they work so you have a broader knowledge of *ngFor, pipes and manipulating data in the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (using [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)):
TS:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  private itemsInRow = 4;
  // dummy array of 14 integers
  private arr = Array.from(Array(14).keys());

  itemInRowRange = Array.from(Array(this.itemsInRow).keys());
  items = of(this.arr);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer" *ngFor="let i of itemInRowRange">
  <div class="box" *ngFor="let item of items | async | slice: i*4 : i*4 + 4">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yk5rlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Restructure the array you are using in the component into an array of arrays each containing 4 elements.

```
let items = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8] ];
```

Here is an example how you would restructure using a loop:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const parentArray = [];
let childArray = [];
items.forEach(item => {
     childArray.push(item);
     if(childArray.length === 4){
          parentArray.push(childArray);
          childArray = [];
     }
});
```

Then nest another ‘ngFor’ inside the first in your template:

```
<div *ngFor=“let item of parentArray”>
    <div *ngFor=“let subItem of item>
        {{ subItem }}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not a very elegant solution, but it is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

component:

```
public items: string[] = [
    "one",
    "twho",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten"
```

]

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i % 4 == 0 || i == 0">
    {{items[i]}}
    {{items[i+1]}}
    {{items[i+2]}}
    {{items[i+3]}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

the general idea is to check whether or not the index of the current element inside the array you are iterating on is a multiple of 4